# Load dependencies by method call

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-3

Is it possible to load some dependencies by method call? I'd like `maven` to call for example `Depencencies.get()`, which would return a collection of other dependencies.
I'm new to `maven`, excuse me if this is a stupid question, I don't know what am I doing half the time.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you declare your dependencies in the `pom.xml`? Why do you want to load the at runtime?

Comment: Well, the case would be "i add a class that requires some dependency (which i specify) and I want maven to download it without having to specify that in pom.xml". Is that a bad idea?

Comment: I fear that is not how Maven works. If you know or specify the dependencies, you could a) add them to the `pom.xml`, or b) make them transitive dependencies of your class (which is probably packaged as a Maven module).

Comment: Okay, looks like I'm not going to do this. It is not crucial for my functionality, I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an API that will allow you to fetch dependencies from maven repositories, you could use [Aether](http://eclipse.org/aether/). I think Aether originated at Sonatype, but it is an Eclipse project now.

For more information:

- See examples, such as [this one](http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git/tree/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/ResolveArtifact.java#n28), of resolving an artifact in the [aether-demo](http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git/) git repository.
- [API docs](http://download.eclipse.org/aether/aether-core/0.9.0.M1/apidocs/)

The downside of Aether is that it adds a *lot* of dependencies to your application.